# Problems with matplotlib animation speed

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

New to matplotlib and trying to explore existing data by iterating through a DataFrame via animation, but it seems very slow,  can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or suggest improvements, have tried playing with frame speed but has little effect so I think its my code, would like to view this 2000 row object in 15 sec give or take.  box is 8gb linex so should be fine, using ipython pop out figure to plot.

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

coef_mean = DataFrame(np.random.rand(2000,50))
def animate(f_frame):
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(coef_mean.columns.values, coef_mean.ix[f_frame])
    plt.ylim(f_coef_min,f_coef_max)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
f_coef_min, f_coef_max = coef_mean.min().min()-.02, coef_mean.max().max()+.02
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=150)
plt.show()
```

any ideas out there what I have done wrong ? many thanks, LW

also to get the popout figure try using

```
%matplotlib qt
```

Comment: sorry sebix missed this, i'm just viewing in qt, not saving, would that affect it ?

Comment: Ok, then I don't have any relevant information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to replot inside the animation function. Instead, you should just update the data of the plot. In your case something like this should work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
custom_plot, = ax.plot(coef_mean.columns.values, coef_mean.ix[0])
ax.set_ylim(f_coef_min,f_coef_max)

def animate(f_frame):
    custom_plot.set_ydata(coef_mean.ix[f_frame])
    return custom_plot,
```

Look at some animation examples for more information. E.g:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html

Comment: clearly better code, but still slow, might be something my end with the install.  many thanks